# Installing XML::Tidy in Strawberry Perl

Tags: xml, tidy, strawberry-perl

When trying to install XML::Tidy in Strawberry Perl

```
C:\>perl --version

This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread

Copyright 1987-2012, Larry Wall

Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.

Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on
this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the
Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.
```

I get the following error when the test are run.

```
Creating new 'Build' script for 'XML-Tidy' version '1.12.B55J2qn'
Building XML-Tidy
  PIP/XML-Tidy-1.12.B55J2qn.tgz
  C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe ./Build -- OK
Running Build test
t\00pod.t .....
t\00pod.t ..... 1/3 #   Failed test 'POD test for blib/lib/XML/Tidy.pm'
#   at C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/Test/Pod.pm line 186.
# blib/lib/XML/Tidy.pm (811): Non-ASCII character seen before =encoding in '®'. Assuming ISO8859-1
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 3.
t\00pod.t ..... Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/3 subtests
t\00podc.t .... ok
t\00small.t ... ok
t\01medium.t .. ok
t\02large.t ... ok
t\03prune.t ... ok
```

I have absolutely no idea what can be wrong here. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install CPAN modules the installer typically runs tests for the module before installing it.

In this case, one of the tests that is run is a test that checks if the in-module documentation is correct; and this fails because it can not recognize the character set. It's really nothing you should worry about too much as this has nothing to do with the code itself.

The best thing to do is to 'force install' the module:

```
cpan> force install XML::Tidy
```

This will still run the test suite, but installs, even if one of the tests is not passing.

BTW I created an RT ticket with a patch to fix this issue: https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=85592